# Call method of dynamic type

Tags: java, dynamic-typing

I have a class hierarchy which looks somewhat like this:

```
class Parent { }
class Child1 extends Parent {}
class Child2 extends Parent {}
class Child3 extends Parent {}
```

In another class I have methods looking like this:

```
void doSomething(Parent p) { //default }
void doSomething(Child1 c) { //implementation for Child 1 }
void doSomething(Child2 c) { //implementation for Child 2 }
```

Currently, when I have something like this

```
Parent p = new Child2();
doSomething(p);
```

the first method, `doSomething(Parent)` is called instead of `doSomething(Child2)`

Let's assume I have a list of items with the static type of Parent and a dynamic type of ChildN. How can I assure the method, provided for the dynamic type is called, without casting. Only for Child3 (no specific doSomething method) I want to call the default implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is called "multi dispatch or "dynamic dispatch" - and doesn't exist in Java.

In Java, the compiler decides which method to pick in case of **overloading**. (and that is what happens when you have three methods with the same name but different parameter types). This happens at compile time, and if your "runtime" Parent object happens to be a Child1 object; that doesn't matter. Because the compiler **fixed** the method to call - as said: java doesn't support dynamic dispatch.

In that sense, the correct Java solution would be to put a method "doSomething()" on your Parent class; and have each child **override** that method to the specific thing.

In case "doSomething()" doesn't really "fit" into this class; you can have a look into the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). Another option would be to use instanceof ... but then you should "hide" the corresponding if/else chain ... again using polymorphism, like:

```
interface DoIt { void doSomething() }
class ParentDoIt implements DoIt ...
  same for Childs

class DoItFactory {
  DoIt getDoIt(Parent p) {
     if (p instanceof Child1) return new Child1DoIt(p)
     ...
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution could be that the doSomething method uses logic from the parameter:

```
class Parent {
    public void neededMethod() {//default}
}

class Child1 {
    public void neededMethod() {//implementation for Child 1}
}
```

Then in your code:

```
void doSomething(Parent p) {
   //more code
   p.neededMethod();
   // code
}
```

If this solution does not fit you because you need some kind of a dispatcher, then you will have to use `instanceof` and then call the proper method:

```
void doSomething (Parent p) {
  if (p instanceof Child1) doSomethingWithChild1(p);
  else if (p instanceof Child2) doSomethingWithChild2(p);
  ...
  else defaultSomething(p);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this.

```
interface SomeAction { void doSomething(); }

class Parent implements SomeAction { //override doSomething here }
class Child1 extends Parent {//override doSomething here }
class Child2 extends Parent {//override doSomething here }
class Child3 extends Parent { // no need to override here}
```

Now

In another class I have methods looking like this

```
void doSomething(SomeAction p) { //default }

Parent p = new Child2();
doSomething(p);

p.doSomething(); // would call Child 2
```

Comment: Thanks, I would have done that but I can't edit my Parent or Child classes

Comment: @Karl Yes here you may have to modify Parent class implement the interface and The another class. If it is not possible then it you may have to check using instanceof which would degrade the performance.